# PHP Sql, returns one row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, fetch

I have the following code that calls a DB function that retrieves all rows from a table and then echo's them in JSON.

```
$key = $db->getKeyPermissions();

    if ($key != false) {
        // use is found
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["key"]["endpoint_name"] = $key["endpoint_name"];
        $response["key"]["live"] = $key["live"];
        $response["key"]["activity_name"] = $key["activity_name"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
```

This is the DB function

```
public function getKeyPermissions()
    {
        $stmt           = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM key_permissions WHERE 1");
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $key = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();
            return $key;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

This all works fine except that it only returns the first row and then stops. Read that you have to loop the `fetch_assoc()` but I couldn't get this working. I would like all rows to be pushed into `$key` and returned, but all attempts result in an array conversion and non-object errors. Can somebody help me along the way?

EDIT:

```
public function getKeyPermissions()
{
    $stmt           = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM key_permissions WHERE 1");
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $key = array();

        while($row = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc()) { //Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object
            $key .= $row; // Array to string conversion 
        }

        $stmt->close();
        return $key;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: `while($key = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc()) { ... }` ? ... just off the top of my head - lacks error trapping though.

Comment: @CD001 Tried that earlier as well, but I am returned error of array conversion and fetch_assoc on a non-object. I edited my post with my new code and a comment behind the lines that return an error.

Comment: `Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object` in which case `get_result()` is returning false.

Comment: `Array to string conversion ` That's not how you append data to an array, try `$key[] = $row;` (`.=` is string concatenation)

Comment: Alright the array conversion error makes a lot more sense then, my bad :) Not sure what to do with the other error though. How can it return false, and what to do against it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to call `get_result` exactly *once*, and `fetch_assoc` as long as there are rows:

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$key = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $key[] = $row;
}

return $key;
```